# Get Class Name When Attribute Is Above It

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I would like to get the Class(or type Name) when my custom attribute is over it.
Return the class name when the attribute is over it
For example:

```
[FoodInfo("CheeseBurger")]
//get this name when the attribute is attached
//           This One
public class Burger : FoodItem, IFood
{
   
}
```

Comment: What's your qestion? What have you tried yourself so far? Who is your code which isn'T working as expected?

Comment: There is no code that is not working! I am curious how to get the type name for when my attribute is over a Class.

Comment: Attributes don't "know" what thing they've been applied to.